# Unable to type text into EditField

Tags: blackberry

The below code does not work as expected on Torch9800 (OS 6.0). I can type text into the hard keyboard but the soft(touch) keyboard will just type one character on below EditField. It works on the simulator but not on device. Is it my code ?
The code is compiled using jre5.0.0

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class MyScreen extends MainScreen {


    public TwitterScreen()
    {
        add(new EditField("", "", 100, EditField.NO_NEWLINE | EditField.FOCUSABLE | EditField.EDITABLE));

    }

}
```

Comment: This issue has been resolved or not?? I cannot right into the EditField... :(